# Heroku account sharing

Tags: heroku

We have several developers, working on the same application (to be deployed on Heroku).
We know they can open separate Heroku accounts, and share the application using "heroku sharing:add".
But is it possible to use a single "team" account? Are there limitations on people logging in simultaneously from different PC's ? Or any other technical reason to avoid it?

Note we're not worried about them overriding each other's deployments, because it's for development (not production), and it's a small team.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Although you can grant limited access to multiple Heroku accounts, only one "Owner" account has privileges to modify the account configuration.

If more than one person needs to modify your account/app configuration (ie: changing/provisioning add-ons, etc), it's best to create a shared e-mail/password stored in a secure password manager like 1Password.  However, this is a hassle and opens up some vulnerability.  It may also be against Heroku's TOS, but isn't likely enforced.

I would recommend using multiple accounts for anyone who needs read-only or deploy access.  I would limit a shared Owner account to the privileged users who need full access.